# How can i call my custom API in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

I have recently  created one API in Laravel .This was structure of that API :

```
method     : post
url        : http://172.22.34.45/mydemo/public/api/v1/file/upload
Form Data
attachment :input file
appVersion :1.0
apiVersion :2.0
type       :1
authToken  :khsdhdy997sdjjsd886
```

In my question is how can i implement this API in  my Codeigniter project.
I know using ajax but in my scenario its not working perfect.Please suggest another option 
eg : calling api from codeigniter controller

Answer (score 1):

By using curl `POST` like this:

```
     $url = "http://172.22.34.45/mydemo/public/api/v1/file/upload";
     $data = array("all the parameters as array elements");
     try{
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $reponse= curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
     }
```

`$data` is the array with values to be sent. `$reponse` will have whatever you return.

Answer (score 0):

This the proven solution to implement RESTFULL Service in CI that I've tested in several projects.Please refer the documentation carefully before implement.It will save your time.
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: Thank you for your replay but i don't want creating new api  in CI.I just want how to use existing laravel Api in my CI project

Comment: Oh i'm sorry.I get misunderstand your request.Please use below code.

$json = file_get_contents('http://172.22.34.45/mydemo/public/api/v1/file/upload', false, $context);
                $data = json_decode($json);